# tensorflow python 2.7 interactive shell: function call fails

Tags: python, tensorflow

[image]

I am studying udacity course: deep learning. Actually it teaches Google's tensorFlow. In Python interactive shell, I define the function softmax, when I invoke it, it says syntaxt error. Why? Any hint.

I have import numpy as np

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> def softmax(x):
...     return np.exp(x);
... softmax([1])
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Are there requirment exact number of indention space?

Comment: Please just post code - Not pictures of code.  Nobody can run your picture.

Comment: the interactive shell is a bit finicky when it comes to whitespace. hit enter again when you are done with the content of your function. you see those "..." instead of ">>>" because the shell is waiting for more code for inside the function

Comment: @Gerrat it is is a simple enough program that we can copy it into the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using interactive, make sure that the `...` is not there. The compiler will include anything in `...` in a function, method, while, or for block. To escape from the `...`, just hit enter again and call the method from `>>>`.

Comment: well i guess i shoulda posted an answer instead of a comment :p

Comment: Yeah @danyamachine. Sorry :(